# calling vim with mpiexec says "Warning: Output is not to a terminal / Warning: Input is not from a terminal"

Tags: terminal, vim, gdb, mpi

My question is a bit technical.

For specific reason, I need to call vim after mpiexec.

Example :

```
mpiexec -n 1 vim mytext.txt
```

But this gives the following warning message:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal 
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

And then, vim does not behave naturally, my input commands are not well interpreted in the editor, and things are not as if I had done simply:

```
vim mytext.txt
```

Any idea on how to redirect correctly input/output from/to my launching terminal in order to be able to use vim after mpiexec ?

Actually, the final goal is to debug in parallel using gdb on a specific proc and to edit functions with vim editor from gdb.

Example :

```
mpiexec -s 1 myprog : gdb myprog
```

So I am starting my program "myprog" on two processes, using gdb on the second one (which is proc 1), and redirecting stdin to proc 1 (thanks to -s 1 [see mpiexec -help]).

But then, if I want to edit a function with vim editor in gdb, I will face the same problems :

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

A quick solution would be to start an xterm window, but I want to avoid that approach:

```
mpiexec myprog : xterm -e gdb myprog
```

Thanks for your help.

Here is my Linux distribution:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Answer (score 0):

`mpiexec` starts up the argument process through ssh, so indeed, input and output are no longer connected with a terminal. What you want is this trick:

```
mpiexec -n 4 xterm -e gdb yourprogram
```

Comment: Thank you,  I was aware of this solution as I mentioned it in my post, but I really want to avoid the xterm trick if possible... I would like to have input/output reconnected with my launching terminal. Is it impossible ?

Comment: I can do it in python with the paramiko module which gives you a handle to the ssh tunnel. I have no idea how to do this with simple shell commands. I think the ssh tunnel is somewhere internal to mpiexec, so you can't pipe to it.

Comment: Btw, why do you want to avoid the xterm approach?

Comment: Thanks, I want to avoid the xterm approach because the loading time for the xterm window is very slow in my environment, so any workaround is welcome :).

Comment: Longer than your debug session? I think if you would have debugged in an xterm you would have been done quicker than this dialog through SE.

Comment: True :p . Let's say, I'm asking this by intellectual curiosity then :). Or more seriously, it may happen that I'm not able to redirect the xterm window, for example if my VPN connection does not allow me to do so, leading to the Error: Can't open display: XXX . In that case, a workaround would be precious.

Comment: `mpiexec -n 1 /bin/bash -l` ?